# Counterclockwise arc integral Latex Symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols, integral, contour

Looking for the code for a Latex integral symbol with a half circle, concave cave down, and an arrow pointing in the clockwise direction.  Does such a symbol exist?

Comment: ∱ U+02231 CLOCKWISE INTEGRAL.  You can use `\intclockwise` with the `unicode-math` package.

Comment: @HenriMenke- not sure I understand your solution since I am looking for the counter clockwise version of the \intclockwise integral.  I have gone through the list and detexify with no success in response to your possible duplicate comment.

Comment: You can generate a mirror image with adjustbox.